# SQL Server "Finish" - what does it do?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm working with some legacy code and have found this:

```
DROP TABLE #Temp
--========================================--
FINISH:
--========================================--
SET @SqlString = 'blah blah blah'
```

It's part of a fairly heavy stored procedure, and when I research via the interwebs the word "finish" is used pretty commonly where people are running jobs that aren't completing, so I am not having a lot of luck finding what this might be for.  It seems to me, at a glance, that the SQL should run just fine without that "`FINISH:`" bit being in there, but it's blue like other SQL keywords so it's obviously used for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a label used for control-of-flow jumps (e.g. `GOTO`).

See the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Ah, so "Finish" isn't itself a keyword, but by adding a colon at the end it becomes a label?